# Doubly linked list c++ crashing after 3rd node

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

So this is a doubly linked list that is supposed to hold names, address, and phone numbe and print them out. It works for the first 3 nodes then suddenly crashes after the the phone number entry on the third node. something is wrong with the pointers I believe but I have tried everything I can think of.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

class node
{
private:
    string elem;
    node* next;
    node* prev;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string address;
    string phoneNumber;
    friend class linkedList;
};

//Linked list
class linkedList
{
public:
linkedList();
void addFrontNode(const string& e);
void addNode(const string& e);
void addNode2(node* nextloc, const string& e);
void addNode3(node* nextloc, const string& e);
void addNode4(node* nextloc, const string& e);
void print();
void search();
node* nextloc;
private:
node* head;
node* tail;


};

void linkedList::addFrontNode(const string &e)
{
node* v = new node;
string firstNameEntry;
string lastNameEntry;
string addressEntry;
string phoneNumberEntry;

cout << "Enter first name: ";
cin >> firstNameEntry;

cout << "Enter last name: ";
cin >> lastNameEntry;

cout << "Enter the address ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, addressEntry);

cout << "Enter a phone number ";
cin >> phoneNumberEntry;

v->elem = firstNameEntry;
v->lastName = lastNameEntry;
v->address = addressEntry;
v->phoneNumber = phoneNumberEntry;
v->next = head;
head = v;


}
void linkedList::addNode(const string &e)
{
node* v = new node;
string firstNameEntry;
string lastNameEntry;
string addressEntry;
string phoneNumberEntry;

cout << "Enter first name: ";
cin >> firstNameEntry;

cout << "Enter last name: ";
cin >> lastNameEntry;

cout << "Enter the address ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, addressEntry);

cout << "Enter a phone number ";
cin >> phoneNumberEntry;
v->elem = firstNameEntry;
v->lastName = lastNameEntry;
v->address = addressEntry;
v->phoneNumber = phoneNumberEntry;

v->next = tail;
tail = v;
tail->next = NULL;
}

void linkedList::addNode2(node* nextloc, const string &e)
{
node* v = new node;
string firstNameEntry;
string lastNameEntry;
string addressEntry;
string phoneNumberEntry;

cout << "Enter first name: ";
cin >> firstNameEntry;

cout << "Enter last name: ";
cin >> lastNameEntry;

cout << "Enter the address ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, addressEntry);

cout << "Enter a phone number ";
cin >> phoneNumberEntry;
v->elem = firstNameEntry;
v->lastName = lastNameEntry;
v->address = addressEntry;
v->phoneNumber = phoneNumberEntry;

nextloc = head -> next;
v->next = nextloc;

v->next = nextloc;
v->prev = nextloc->prev;
nextloc->prev = v;
}
void linkedList::addNode3(node* nextloc, const string &e)
{
node* v = new node;
string firstNameEntry;
string lastNameEntry;
string addressEntry;
string phoneNumberEntry;

cout << "Enter first name: ";
cin >> firstNameEntry;

cout << " Enter last name: ";
cin >> lastNameEntry;

cout << " Enter the address ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, addressEntry);

cout << " Enter a phone number ";
cin >> phoneNumberEntry;
v->elem = firstNameEntry;
v->lastName = lastNameEntry;
v->address = addressEntry;
v->phoneNumber = phoneNumberEntry;

v->next = nextloc;
v->prev = nextloc->prev;
nextloc->prev = v;
}

void linkedList::addNode4(node* nextloc, const string &e)
{
node* v = new node;
string firstNameEntry;
string lastNameEntry;
string addressEntry;
string phoneNumberEntry;

cout << "Enter first name: ";
cin >> firstNameEntry;

cout << " Enter last name: ";
cin >> lastNameEntry;

cout << " Enter the address ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, addressEntry);

cout << " Enter a phone number ";
cin >> phoneNumberEntry;
v->elem = firstNameEntry;
v->lastName = lastNameEntry;
v->address = addressEntry;
v->phoneNumber = phoneNumberEntry;

v->next = nextloc;
v->prev = nextloc->prev;
nextloc->prev->next = v;
nextloc->prev = v;
}
linkedList::linkedList() :head(NULL) {}

void linkedList::print()
{
node* v = new node;
v = head;
while (v != NULL)
{
    cout << v->elem << " ";
    cout << v->lastName << " ";
    cout << v->address << " ";
    cout << v->phoneNumber;
    v = v->next;
}
}
void linkedList::search()
{
node* v = new node;
v = tail;
string lastNameSearch;
cout << "Enter a last name to search ";
cin >> lastNameSearch;
while (v != NULL)
{
    if (v->lastName == lastNameSearch)
    {
        cout << v->elem;
        cout << v->address;
        cout << v->phoneNumber;

    }
    v = v->prev;
}
}
int main()
{
string node1;
string node2;
string node3;
string node31;
string node4;
string node5;

linkedList list;
list.addFrontNode(node1);
list.addNode(node2);
list.addNode2(list.nextloc, node3);
list.addNode3(list.nextloc, node4);
list.addNode4(list.nextloc, node5);
list.print();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using this rather than `std::list`?

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, possibly for the implementation experience?

Comment: You don't need all of this code to provide a [mcve].  Remove all of those input and output statements -- they clutter up the code and are unnecessary.  Just create an empty list and fill it with 3 nodes with hard-coded data.

Comment: That's a totally valid reason, just, if there is no reason, there is an easy solution.

Comment: One of the best tools for troubleshooting a linked list (or any pointer-based data structure) is to visualize it with a pen and paper. Draw the sucker. Then follow the instructions in your code to the letter and modify the drawing. If you can't get to the end configuration, you'll know pretty fast, you'll have a really good idea where you went wrong, and probably a few ideas on how to fix it.

Comment: It is for an assignment and we are supposed to create everything for ourselves and cannot use STL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues.

1. If you use `addFrontNode()` to add first node, you must set your `tail`. 
   Change this:

   ```
   v->next = head;
   head = v;
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   v->next = NULL;
   head = v;
   tail = v;
   ```
2. Your function `addNode()` doesn't add to list correctly, try calling `print` and you will see, no node is added by this function.
   Change this:

   ```
   v->next = tail;
   tail = v;
   tail->next = NULL;
   ```

   To this:

   ```
   tail->next = v;
   v->next = NULL;
   tail = v;
   ```
3. In `main()` just use `addFrontNode()` to add first and then use `addNode()` to add all others. After this your code worked as expected.
4. Didn't understand meaning of variable `nextloc`, might be the source of problems.

Overall recommendation: create one function to add node

Answer (score 0):

The code is indeed in need of re-write, but I don't want to repeat recommendations from the first answer. I however, believe that the question was about the reasons of the crash. It's because while copy-pasting the code, you added 2 extra lines to your addNode2:

```
void linkedList::addNode2(node* nextloc, const string &e)
{
...
nextloc = head -> next;
v->next = nextloc;
...
}
```

[Comment out at least first of them](https://repl.it/Mw5p/0) and it won't crash any more (but this wouldn't make it better, really).